# Printing an inline SVG (in mm) from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, svg, printing

I have to print my SVG straight from the browser, but I have no idea how to do that.

The locations and sizes of the SVG's elements are important, that's why the numbers are all in mm.
It has to print on pre-printed paper, in pre-printed containers.

The SVG currently looks something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="col-md-12 designerCanvas" id="svgLabel" width="240mm" height="90mm" viewbox="0 0 240 90">
    <image class="svg" id="img-160-68" visibility="visible" x="160.202" y="68.0135" width="14.0043" height="14.0043" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/Icons/icon02.png" />
    <image class="svg" id="img-175-68" visibility="visible" x="175.791" y="68.0135" width="14.0043" height="14.0043" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/Icons/icon05.png" />
    <image class="svg" id="img-191-68" visibility="visible" x="191.381" y="68.0135" width="14.0043" height="14.0043" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/images/Icons/icon07.png" />
    <text class="svg" id="txt-0-5" font-family="Arial" font-size="1.64233" visibility="visible" text-anchor="start" x="0.5285" y="5.5489" height="33.29333142498542" width="79.26983672615574">
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">[EN] Some Title: </tspan>
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">There is some text here.</tspan>
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">Even more text here. </tspan>
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">WOW, a third line.</tspan>
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">You're overdoing it</tspan>
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">Please</tspan>
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">STAHP</tspan>
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">No More!!</tspan>
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">That's it</tspan>
        <tspan x="0.5285" dy="1.6423">I'm outta here....</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Do note that the paper's (=SVG canvas) width and height come from the DB and can have several values.

The x, y, width and height of the elements now don't have mm, as the viewbox and units combo of the SVG canvas solve that, though I can add it if needed.

Client only wants me to support IE11+, though I myself want to support recent Chrome and FF as well.

I could load the drawing in a fresh (temporary) window to print it, though I'm not sure it'll print on the correct coördinates like that.
Maybe creating a PDF and print that is the way to go, though no idea how to send the svg to that.

The web application itself is an ASP.NET MVC (Core), with plain javascript and jQuery added to the front end.

Couldn't find much info on the web on the topic, besides printing a SVG in pixels on default paper, but I'm pretty sure the elements will get printed in the wrong location/size that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't rely on `mm` values printing at the correct 1:1 scale.  You''ll need to test the output on a real printer and adjust the scale of your SVG based on that particulare computer/browser/printer combination [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076964/svg-for-print-with-scale/46078488#46078488)

Comment: Can't really do that as this is going to be a global tool and there are countless computer/browser/printer combinations. Isn't there a way to easily convert the SVG image to a PDF or so as that can handle those combinations without any need for countless configurations?

Comment: You don't have much choice. Even a PDF ican be problematic. If your customers are international, you would need to handle both metric A paper sizes and US Letter paper sizes. Even then, you couldn't guarantee that someone's printer will print the page at 1:1.

Comment: It'll be custom paper sizes, the 240mm x 90mm SVG in the example will be printed on a  240mm x 90mm paper. Other SVG will be on other paper sizes, but a svg drawing will plways represent a full sheet.