# A4 size SVG doesn't fill whole A4 paper in printing

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, svg, printing

I have a program that can output a multi-level SVG label, and I set all unit with "mm", there is some example:

```
SVG(Container width="210mm" height="594mm")
  SVG(A4 size width="210mm" height="297mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
  SVG(A4 size width="210mm" height="297mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
    SVG(Label size width="105mm" height="99mm")
```

Each A4 size SVG will have a little deviation on end of paper, so when I print count of above 3 papers, I will see paper3's top on paper2's bottom.

I have tried to set stroke as transparent and stroke-width to 0 but it's seem about not the problem with stroke.

Here is the complete SVG code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="210mm" height="2673mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="210mm" height="297mm">
        <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <svg x="0mm" y="297mm" width="210mm" height="297mm">
        <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <svg x="0mm" y="594mm" width="210mm" height="297mm">
        <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <svg x="0mm" y="891mm" width="210mm" height="297mm">
        <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <svg x="0mm" y="1188mm" width="210mm" height="297mm">
        <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <svg x="0mm" y="1485mm" width="210mm" height="297mm">
        <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <svg x="0mm" y="1782mm" width="210mm" height="297mm">
        <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <svg x="0mm" y="2079mm" width="210mm" height="297mm">
        <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <svg x="0mm" y="2376mm" width="210mm" height="297mm">
        <svg x="0mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="0mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="105mm" y="99mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#FF0000" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
        <svg x="0mm" y="198mm" width="105mm" height="99mm">
            <rect stroke="#fff" fill="#00FF00" stroke-width="0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Here's print preview in Chrome
[image: print preview]

And here's [SVG file](https://storage.googleapis.com/mynet-public/numbers.svg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "real world" coordinate units, such as `mm`, do not correspond with actual real world measurements.

For simplicity, SVG (actually this is a CSS thing), defines an inch as 96 CSS pixels (`px`).
This roughly corresponded with the approximate resolution of screens back when this was decided.  So really, `1in` is just a shorthand for `96px`.

How a browser decides what `96px` corresponds to, when printing, is up to them.  And none of them (AFAIK) make any attempt to try and match up the CSS "DPI" and the printer DPI.

You will need to manually adjust the scale of your SVGs by an appropriate amount for your browser and printer combination.

This previous question may be of use with this: [SVG for print with scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076964/svg-for-print-with-scale)

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply. Just like you said, there is some float error(0.12345 in code but 0.12 on browser)